# Does XPath support else-if statement?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Recently, I wrote some personal programs using XSLT. I am surprised that XPATH has 'if then else' statement, no 'else if'.

For example, I can only use:

```
if *** then ***
else ***
```

but I can't use:

```
if *** then ***
else if *** then ***
else ***
```

Does XPath support else-if statement? The only way to simulate else-if is nesting if else?

Comment: What's wrong with nesting an `if` in an `else`? Does it work or not?

Comment: Many languages support if-elseif as nested statements according to their grammar-we just indent them like they're not. Some have actual elsif constructs, but certainly not all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An expression such as

```
if (x=3) 
  then 1 
else if (x=4) 
  then 5 
else 6
```

is perfectly legal in XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`xsl:choose`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#xsl-choose)

> The xsl:choose element selects one among a number of possible
>   alternatives. It consists of a sequence of one or more `xsl:when`
>   elements followed by an optional `xsl:otherwise` element. Each `xsl:when`
>   element has a single attribute, test, which specifies an expression.
>   The content of the `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise` elements is a sequence
>   constructor.
>
> When an xsl:choose element is processed, each of the `xsl:when` elements
>   is tested in turn (that is, in the order that the elements appear in
>   the stylesheet), until one of the `xsl:when` elements is satisfied. If
>   none of the `xsl:when` elements is satisfied, then the xsl:otherwise
>   element is considered, as described below.

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="expression1">
    ... some output ...
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="expression2">
    ... some output ...
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    ... some output ....
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```